# Importing multiple excel files for data analysis

Tags: python, excel, pandas, analysis

I have a few lines of code and a small dilemma, so I wrote this code for the purpose of analysis and it takes up an excel file reads it as a Dataframme using pandas, if I'm not wrong, I'm pretty new to coding, and bins the file into multiples of 5. Nonetheless, I was able to make it work with one file, but I was wondering what could be done to make it read multiple excel files apply the same binning to each and output each individual analyzed file. The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
from pandas import ExcelWriter

data = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/Book1.xlsx')
counts, bins, patches = plt.hist(data.values, bins=range(0, 
int(max(data.values)+5), 5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin_leftedge': bins[:-1], 'count': counts})
plt.title('Data')
plt.xlabel('Neuron')
plt.ylabel('# of Spikes')
plt.show()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/jorge/Desktop/Data/output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

Also, the ultimate goal is to have be able to have the code determine the max value for ALL inputted and analyzed excel files and having the code save the max value of all of them (whether it be 2, 3, 5, 27 excel files) and comparing each excel file to THAT max code, please any help is greatly appreciated. Again, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but you'll want to start by defining the input files. If this is a console module, then you can specify each file path using ```my_module.py C:\path\to\Book1.xls C:\path\to\Book2.xls``` and iterating over those using ```for book_path in sys.argv:```

Comment: you can learn more about ```sys.argv``` [in this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Comment: Put your process in a function that accepts a filename as input and returns the analyzed result, then use a loop to iterate over the files passing the filenames to the function and doing something with the return value.

Comment: Use the os module with smth like:                                                                                   for file in os.listdir(/Users/user/Desktop/Data/):                                                                                            
    data = pd.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/Data/{0}'.format(file))                     ..... You casn read more about it at the docs of the os module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
import os
import re
                                                                                                                    for files in os.listdir(r"/Users/user/Desktop/Data"):
    if re.search(r".*.xlsx", files):
        data = pd.read_excel("//Users//jorge//Desktop//Data/{0}".format(files))
```

.... put your code here...

This will loop through all your ecel files in the dir and you can reslise the desired operations on it